# How to build bootstrap using jspm and bootstrap-sass

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass, gulp, gulp-sass, jspm

I'm just starting to dig into SASS, and trying to figure out how to build `bootstrap` from the `bootstrap-sass` module installed with `jspm` as a "dev dependency" - which I'm not sure is correct.

I installed `sass` from ruby gems.  Since I'm using jspm, do I need to install `gulp` and create a gulp task, or should jspm take care of everything for me?

If gulp is required, how would that work with jspm package management?

I must admit, all of these crossovers are a little confusing. :)

UPDATE:
Following steps

I removed the JSPM version of bootstrap-sass (because running the gulp task resulted in errors about bootstrap-mincer missing), and instead installed from `npm`:

`npm install bootstrap-sass --save-dev`

Since I still need the bootstrap javascript, I installed via JSPM:

`jspm install bootstrap`

gulpfile.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

var SASS_PATH = "./node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/**/*.scss";

gulp.task('sass', function () {
  return gulp.src(SASS_PATH)
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/styles/'));
});

gulp.task('sass:watch', function () {
  gulp.watch(SASS_PATH, ['sass']);
});

gulp.task('default', function() {
  // place code for your default task here
});
```

Running tasks doesn't produce any output into `./public/styles`:

```
$ gulp sass
[18:52:30] Using gulpfile ~/path_to_project/gulpfile.js
[18:52:30] Starting 'sass'...
[18:52:30] Finished 'sass' after 37 ms
```

If I can get the gulp tasks to work, then I could load bootstrap.js from JSPM's System.js, and load the css independently.

Answer (score 1):

Gulp should be install from NPM because it's a build task.

Ruby is not mandatory. Instead of `ruby sass`, you can now use `node-sass` :
https://npmjs.org/package/node-sas

```
npm install node-sass --save-dev
```

and use the `gulp sass` task :
https://github.com/dlmanning/gulp-sass

```
npm install gulp --save-dev
npm install gulp-sass --save-dev
```

(please note that the `gulp-sass` node module already include the `node-sass` node module as dependency, so install `node-sass` is not necessary)

then add the `sass` task in your `gulpfile`:

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

gulp.task('sass', function () {
  return gulp.src('./sass/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'));
});

gulp.task('sass:watch', function () {
  gulp.watch('./sass/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
});
```

Comment: Damn, that's easy. Will give it a try.

Comment: I'm getting there. I've added more information to my question.

Answer (score 0):

I would run npm commands for installing build tools:

```
npm install jspm --save-dev
npm install gulp --save-dev
npm install gulp-sass --save-dev
```

Then jspm commands for installing dependancies:

```
jspm install bootstrap-sass
```

Then in your gulpfile.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass');

gulp.task('sass', function () {
  return gulp.src('./src/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/css'));
});

gulp.task('watch', function () {
    gulp.watch('./src/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['sass', 'watch']);
```

In your all.scss:

```
// shared across all components
$icon-font-path: "../../jspm_packages/github/twbs/bootstrap-sass@3.3.6/assets/fonts/bootstrap/";
@import "../../jspm_packages/github/twbs/bootstrap-sass@3.3.6/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "../../jspm_packages/github/twbs/bootstrap-sass@3.3.6/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap";

// components
@import './header/header';
```

Then run your gulp task:

```
gulp
```

Comment: You can use `System.normalizeSync('bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap')` so you don't need to depend on versionnumbers on importing.